# Make a crash notifier for ios app

Tags: objective-c, crash

I'm making an app that involves manipulating the data of photos. Often editing the photo's data will cause a crash that is unavoidable. I'm wondering if there's a way for a window or alert to appear upon a crash, telling the user to restart and try again. Any tips or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: "Often editing the photo's data will cause a crash that is unavoidable." - ***What?*** That's a terrible approach. Never let your app crash. There's no such thing as an "unavoidable crash", at most you don't know how to fix it. But I'm not interested in whether or not you can fix it. Just fix it.

Comment: @userXXX A good tutorial for beginning to learn is fundamental, I think the first page of Google for "Objective-C tutorial" shall be sufficient for now (don't buy books, they won't be up-to-date given the speed Apple changes the language with). The read a lot the class reference docs on developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this thread to catch Uncaught Exceptions

[UncaughtExceptions Handler](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use these codes.

https://github.com/amazingsyco/CrashReporter

https://github.com/bitstadium/PLCrashReporter

Thank you!